# No module named 'redis' with python code

Tags: python, redis

I have checked

```
redis-server --version
Redis server v=4.0.8 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-4.0.3 bits=64 build=4d30adc486b198e5
```

If I try to run my code

```
  File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
    import redis
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis'
```

Why?

Comment: You probably need `pip install redis`

Comment: Have you installed the redis python package?

Comment: @chrisz Yes,that's it,works fine.

Comment: make sure you `sudo pip install redis`

Comment: @SuaMorales not necessarily.  There is no reason to use `sudo` if you don't have to.  In fact, I would say it's bad practice to default to using sudo to install python packages.

Comment: @chrisz recommended in the python docs: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis . Generally agree, tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem running from inside a Jupyter Notebook. Very strange, if I used !pip freeze or !conda list it would throw the same error.

I eventually stumbled upon this post: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/
And the code snippet that ultimately worked:

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install redis
```